# Find 'n' by decrementing numbers from 'z' with the amount of numbers equal to 'x'

Tags: python, math

Say I have **n**  let's say it has a value of `27` now I have another variable lets say **x** is equals to `6` and a final variable **z** equals `9`. We are going to find **n** by decrementing numbers from **z** with the amount of numbers equal to **x**.

For example, the number **27** should have an answer of  `8 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 1 = 27` but the problem is you do not where to start, or how much the decrement value should be and also numbers cannot be duplicated. So the only solution I have now is to bruteforce it which takes soooo long. This is my current solution for it :

(idk if this works, I haven't got a "found" print)

```
for x in range(9**6):
    for a in range(9):
        for b in range(9):
            for c in range(9):
                for d in range(9):
                    for e in range(9):
                        for f in range(9):
                            _arr = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
                            arr = []
                            
                            for g in _arr:
                                if g not in _arr:
                                    arr.append(g)
                            
                            result = ((a + 1)  + (b + 1) + (c + 1) + (d + 1) + (e + 1) + (f + 1))
                            if len(arr) == 6 and result == 27 :
                                print(f"→ found! | answer : {result}")
```

What algorithms or theories should I use to solve this, or if its even possible? So far I've looked into GMP, Numpy libraries etc. but do not know in what way I would implement those.

Comment: very sorry if the problem isn't clear. What I am trying to find is its like the factor of 27 but in addition with 6 numbers thus why `8 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 1 = 27` → [8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1] = 6 numbers. x is the maximum amount of loops we would take to bruteforce this 6 numbers, and for g in _arr is used, since the 6 numbers cannot have duplicated values it is there to filter it hence why there is a len(arr) == 6. I hope this clears up everything :)

Comment: *"the number 27 should have an answer of 8 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 1 = 27"*: Why not 8+7+5+4+2+1, or 8+7+6+3+2+1?

Comment: Are you saying that you always want a result made up of 6 "factors"? What if there are multiple solutions? What if the input value is less than 21? Is zero allowed? Is the result always comprised of single digit "factors"?

Comment: @trincot I know that there would be more combinations than `8 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 1` but atleast one of them would do. @Stuart the values of the variables must connect otherwise it just doesn't calculate, the result of the problem should be scalable as I imagined it so it doesn't matter if its just single digit factors so for example if you want to get the factors of 720 with max range of 102 with a "14" numbers it would be → `1 + 5 + ..(10 more numbers here).. + 97 + 102` = 720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to brute force this. You can start out by the minimum sum you can get with the number of terms (i.e., 1+2+3+4..). Then consider that the greatest value can be increased up to the maximum value. This increment can be applied to the second greatest as well, ...etc. We can determine by division how many of these increments we need. The remainder of this division will determine how much the greatest value that didn't change should be incremented.

Here is an implementation:

```
def solve(target, num_terms, max_value):
    total = num_terms * (num_terms + 1) // 2  # Triangular number
    if total > target:
        raise ValueError("target is too small")
    need = target - total
    diff = max_value - num_terms
    if need > num_terms * diff:
        raise ValueError("target is too great")
    shift = need // diff
    if num_terms == shift:
        return list(range(max_value - shift + 1, max_value + 1))
    return (
        list(range(1, num_terms - shift))
        + [num_terms - shift + (need % diff)]
        + list(range(max_value - shift + 1, max_value + 1))
    )
```

Applied on the example in the question:

```
print(solve(27, 6, 9))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Very clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach**

- A backtracking approach worked quickly for the problem of number 27
- Backtracking was too slow for the larger number i.e. abandoned after 30 minutes on the more difficult problem of 780
- Was able to quickly solved both problems using [Constraint Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming)
- Implemented constraint programming using [Google OrTools Constraint Satisfaction](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp)
- Stopped at first solution found with each run

Constraints

- Have a given number of numbers
- Numbers values range from 1 to a max value
- Numbers are distinct
- Numbers add to the desired sum

Performance

- OR-Tools was able to find solutions to the posted problems in milliseconds on a 10+-year-old Windows desktop

**Code**

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

def find_factors(required_sum, max_value, n_numbers):
    '''
        Find factors that:
        : required_sum- sum to n
        : max_value numbers(numbers from 1 to max_value inclusive)
        - n_numbers - number of numbers to find
        
        Approach
        
        Use google ortools constraint satisfaction
        Reference: https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp
    '''

    # Create model
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Create constraint variables
    number_choices = []
    for i in range(n_numbers):
        # numbers from 1 to max_value
        number_choices.append(model.NewIntVar(1, max_value, f"number {i}"))

    # Add constraints to variables
    #   Sum of numbers equals required sum
    model.Add(sum(number_choices)==required_sum)

    #   All numbers are different
    model.AddAllDifferent(number_choices)

    #   Numbers are in Descending order
    for i in range(n_numbers-1):
        model.Add(number_choices[i] > number_choices[i+1])

    # Solve for constsraints and report results
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.num_workers = 10
    status = solver.Solve(model)

    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        return ([solver.Value(v) for v in number_choices])
    else:
        return None  # no solution found
```

**Testing**

```
print(find_factors(27, 9, 6))
# Output: [9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1]

print(find_factors(780, 102, 14))
# Output: [102, 59, 58, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46]
```

**Timing**

```
%timeit find_factors(27, 9, 6)
# Result: 3.13 ms ± 489 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit find_factors(780, 102, 14)
# Result: 7.95 ms ± 396 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @gushkash -- thanks.  It's an illustration of how constraint programming allows you to solve difficult combinatorial problems efficiently by just stating the constraints.  Trincot's solution illustrates a more efficient customized algorithm for this particular problem. But, a custom algorithm is generally hard to discover with many problems so this provides a more general approach as illustrated by [Google OR-Tools for Constraint Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hod0L0zfnZs&t=7987s).