# Is there a non-bruteforce solution for this problem? (python)

Tags: python

This is a continuation of my previous post ([Find 'n' by decrementing numbers from 'z' with the amount of numbers equal to 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73125754)). The problem from my previous post was I am trying to find the possible combinations to get the sum of **27** with a maximum value and a required length, for example, if you have a maximum value of **9** and a required length of **6** you'd get something like `(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)` or `(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9)` if you sum up `(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)` or `(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9)` this will be equals to **27** `(1 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 8 = 27)`. From my previous post, turns out you could solve it by finding the first pattern that comes up and from the solutions given from the previous post it is actually not that hard as I imagined

Now my problem is that - what if I am trying to find a specific pattern for example for **27** I want to get`[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]` and not `[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9]` (as shown from the solutions from the previous post by @trincot). I tried doing this with constraint programming but I made no progress with it.

So my current idea for it, since there are many patterns to get a sum of **27** from a range of **9**, we should get a trait unique to the pattern we have, so I'd get the gaps between the exact pattern in an array that I want, then divide it with the higher value then sum it up then we get something unique(?) for the pattern *(Not proven this is unique, only an assumption)* for example:

```
arr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
for i in range(len(arr)):
     if i > 0:
         required_avg += (arr[i] - arr[i - 1]) / arr[i])

# → result should be : 1.5333333333333334
```

in numpy :

```
np_array = np.asrray(arr)
required_avg = np.sum(np.diff(np_array) / np_array[1:])

# → result should be : 1.5333333333333334
```

Now this *required_avg* I am assuming is unique to the pattern that we want. My current solution again is to bruteforce it like from my previous post, but for example I want a larger value to solve something like 427 but from my current solution it takes very long .

Here is my solution : *(Note: This solution also has a minimum value this is not present in the previous post)*

```
arr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]

import numpy as np
import threading, time

required_length = 6
required_avg = 1.5333333333333334
required_sum = 27
required_first_index = 1
required_last_index = 9

found = False
def crack_avg():
    global required_length, required_avg, required_sum, required_first_index, required_last_index, found
    
    np_array = np.random.choice(range(required_first_index, required_last_index + 1), required_length, replace=False)
    np_array.sort()
    current_avg = np.sum(np.diff(np_array) / np_array[1:])
    current_sum = sum(np_array)

    if (current_avg == required_avg and current_sum == required_sum):
        print(f"→ found! sequence : {np_array}")
        found = True
    
start_time = time.time()
while (found == False):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=crack_avg)
    thread.start()
print(f"→ time : {time.time() - start_time}s")
```

However as stated above, for example I want to solve for 427, with a required length of 14, maximum number of 102, minimum of 2. This would take a very long time to solve as I am approaching the problem with bruteforcing. Here are the variables for it if you'd like to try :

```
# the length of the pattern 
required_length = 14

# unique traits to find the current pattern we are looking for
required_avg = 3.3227157416506903
required_sum = 427

# pattern must have a minimum value of 2, maximum value of 102 in its sequence
required_first_index = 2
required_last_index = 102
```

If you were to solve this, how would you do it? **(Preferably no bruteforcing)**

*(A solution for constraint programming would be insanely great as I am trying to learn it!)*

Comment: If you have working code from a previous question, and are looking for performance improvements, perhaps you should ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to solve here, and what criteria you are applying when saying you want one sequence of numbers rather than another one. To me, an obvious place to start when looking for a sequence of `x` nearly consecutive numbers that add up to `n` is with `n/x` and the integers around it. For your example of 427 and 14, I'd try starting with `[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]` (which puts `427/14 = 30.5` right in between the middle values of the sequence) and adjusting to taste.

Comment: @Blckknght What I am trying to solve here is getting a specific pattern from a set of requirements for example, if we are going to solve `427` with a set of requirements that are : a minimum value of `2`, a maximum value of `102`, a required length of `14` and a unique trait of "required avg" `3.3227157416506903` the answer we would be looking for would be `102 + 95 + 76 + 43 + 33 + 21 + 16 + 11 + 9 + 7 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 1` . Your answer of `[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]` is also correct, if "required_avg" was not in the equation, but we need to get that specific one

Comment: OK, I've read more of your code. The "required average" isn't an average, it's some kind of proportional difference, which is weird, but doable. But there are bigger issues. First, you're trying to exactly match a floating point value. That's a bad idea, since floating point imprecision means you may never find the value, even with the right sequence. But the biggest issue is that your code isn't "brute forcing" the problem, you're *randomly guessing* sequences (not even ones that add up properly) and hoping they add up *and* have your "average". That's like sorting with bogosort, but worse!

Comment: haha, yeah my solution isn't really efficient. Do you think such problem is impossible to solve? or is it somehow doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to express is: There is a set of numbers, specify a certain number of numbers which can be used, and the result of the sum is the target value.

So I think it is more appropriate to use constraint programming to solve this problem. I use Google OR-Tools and here are the code:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

first_index = 1
last_index = 9
length = 6
target = 27

# 得到所有能用的数字的list
# get a list with all numbers which can used
all_numbers = list(range(first_index, last_index+1))

# 创建约束规划模型
# create constraint programming model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# 创建表示每个数字出现次数的list，每个数字只能出现0次或1次
# create a list representing the number of occurrences of each number, each number can only appear 0 time or 1 time
var_set = [model.NewIntVar(0, 1, "{}".format(i)) for i in all_numbers]

# 添加约束：所有被选择的数字之和是目标值
# add constraint: the sum of all selected numbers is the target value
model.Add(sum(var_set[i] * all_numbers[i] for i in range(len(all_numbers))) == target)
# 添加约束：只能选择(length)个数字
# add constraint: Only (length) numbers can be selected
model.Add(sum(var_set) == length)

# 解决方案打印器
# solution printer
class VarArraySolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):

    def __init__(self, variables):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__variables = variables
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.__solution_count += 1
        for v in self.__variables:
            if self.Value(v) == 1:
                print(v, end=' ')
        print()

    def solution_count(self):
        return self.__solution_count

# 创建解决器并导入模型计算出结果
# create a solver and import the model to calculate the result
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter(var_set)
solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = True
status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)
```

The output is:

[image]

Then, set it to solve for 427, with a required length of 14, maximum number of 102, minimum of 2:

```
first_index = 2
last_index = 102
length = 14
target = 427
```

The output is:

[image]

Too many results!

Answer (score 0):

So the first difference from your previous post is, you introduced required min and max values. For this, the solution given to the previos answer is still valid: instead of finding six numbers in range `1..9` that sum up to `27` you now want to find four numbers in range `2..8` that sum up to `27-1-9 = 17`.

The second difference is, you want to find a *specific* solution. And you give an example in which you already *know* the solution you want, and try to make the code produce that solution. Honestly I don't see the point here: for small examples you can surely find by hand a solution you like, but a code that accepts it as an input and returns it as its output doesn't seem so useful; while for larger examples how are you going to define what the preferred solution is?

IMO it would be more interesting to establish a criterium for what the best solution is, and then let the code find that solution. For instance you may say, I want the solution with the lowest (or the greatest) variance or perhaps standard deviation, or anything.

Depending on the criterium you define you may be able to directly compute the best solution: for instance, the mimimum stdev for 4 numbers summing up to `18` is obviously given by `[3,4,5,6]`. With other criteria you may need to find all the solutions and compare them to see which one is the best.